# изменение ссылок и последующий апдейт html

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, cheerio

Необходимо найти все ссылки на странице и изменить их при парсинге.
Я грабблю yandex.ru и хочу все ссылки заменить на google.com
и далее вывести уже готовую страницу

Подключаю express, cheerio (для работы с DOM), request (для получения страницы).

```
request(url, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(body); //получаем страницу

        $('body').find('a').each(function() { // находим и меняем все ссылки
          $(this).attr('href').replace(/(yandex.ru)/g, "google.com")
        });

        app.get('/', function (req, res) { // выводим страницу
            res.send(body);
          });

    } else {
        console.log("Произошла ошибка: " + error);
    }
});
```

Body у меня получается без апдейта, т.е. все ссылки по прежнему yandex.ru.
функция с изменением ссылок работает.если выводить `res.send($.html())`
body всё равно без изменений. Как заставить cheerio после моих манипуляций апдейтнуть body?

Comment: Даже при выводе $('body').html() после манипуляций, он остается прежним

Comment: а куда сохраняется результат преобразования, просто мне кажется что вы выводите первоначальный `body`, но я могу ошибаться. И точку наверное лучше заэкранировать

Comment: `$(this).attr('href').replace(/(yandex.ru)/g, "google.com")` тут нет никакого присваивания, это `replace` вникуда

Comment: В том то и дело, как это правильно всё переписать?)

Comment: @Danil Сразу же на стартовой странице https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio видно что текст получается после вызова `$.html()`, у вас этого в коде не видно. Попробуйте заменить `res.send(body);` на `res.send($.html());`

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg под кодом я как раз писал что такой вариант тоже не сработал

Comment: @Danil "такой вариант тоже не сработал"(с) да, точно, я не заметил. Обратите внимание на это https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#each-functionindex-element-, там идет присваивание. Вам уже кстати написали, что `replace` вникуда

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ (если кому интересно):

```
$('body').find('a').each(function() {
       var result = $(this).attr('href').replace(/(yandex.ru)/g, "google.com")
       $(this).attr("href", result)
    })
```

Спасибо что навели на мысль

Comment: Можно в `each`  добавить `function ( i, el )`, а строку укоротить до `el.attribs.href = el.attribs.href.replace( /yandex\.ru/g, 'google.com' )`, и точка должна быть заэкранирована, иначе это не точка, а любой символ.